# Проблема при удалении директории

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Прошу вас помочь в решении следующей задачи. Существует функция для удаления директории:

```
BOOL DeleteDir(DWORD B_Id)
{
    ASSERT(m_pDatabaseMng);
    if (!m_pDatabaseMng)
        return FALSE;

    try
    {
        std::list<DWORD> lstIds;

        CString sSQL;
        sSQL.Format(_T("SELECT ID FROM BUGO WHERE PARENT_ID=%d"), B_Id);

        ADODB::_RecordsetPtr spRS = m_pDatabaseMng->OpenRecordset(sSQL);
        long nRecordCount = spRS->GetRecordCount();

        for (long nRecord = 0; nRecord < nRecordCount; ++nRecord)
        {
            lstIds.push_back((long)spRS->GetFields()->GetItem(_T("ID"))->GetValue());
            spRS->MoveNext();
        }

        spRS->Close();

        for (std::list<DWORD>::iterator it = lstIds.begin(); it != lstIds.end(); ++it)
        if (!DeleteDir(*it))
        return FALSE;

        sSQL.Format(_T("DELETE FROM BUGO WHERE ID=%d"), B_Id);
        VERIFY(m_pDatabaseMng->ExecuteSQL(sSQL));

    }
    catch (_com_error& e)
    {
        if(AfxMessageBox(CString(_T("Удаление каталога невозможно!\n")) + (LPCTSTR)e.Description()+ CString(_T("\nПродолжить удаление?")),MB_OKCANCEL)== IDYES);
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

На данный момент происходит следующее если мы не можем удалить директорию, то вываливается сообщение из catch при нажатии на кнопку ОК удаляются все каталоги до достижения условия if (!DeleteDir(*it)). 
Теперь вопрос как мне сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку ОК у меня удалялись все возможные директории, а не до первой, которую невозможно удалить. А при нажатии на ОТМЕНА происходило то что и сейчас. Можно ли это реализовать в catch, или придется что-то переписывать?
Прошу помощи уважаемые...

Comment: Не понятно в каком месте вываливается исключение. 

Comment: for (std::list<DWORD>::iterator it = lstIds.begin(); it != lstIds.end(); ++it)
        if (!DeleteDir(*it))
        return FALSE;

Вот тут вываливается исключение, если не можем удалить, то удаляем до первого невозможного, в данном случае при нажатии кнопки ОК. Но надо сделать чтобы это было при нажатии ОТМЕНА, а при ОК она удаляла все возможное, чтобы можно было перескочить через данное исключение, и проверить все что за ним.

Comment: вы считаете это ответом на вопрос?

Comment: А как вам вариант, обработку исключения перенести в цикл? Т.е. как-то так:

    for (std::list<DWORD>::iterator it = lstIds.begin(); it != lstIds.end(); ++it)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!DeleteDir(*it))
                return FALSE;
        }
        catch(_com_error& e)
        {
            //Если нажали cancel, то return, иначе просто цикл продолжится.
        }
    }

Comment: не получается так сделать, вываливает ошибки.

Comment: А что за ошибки, возможно их можно решить или два блока try-catch, внутренний отлавливающий исключения в DeleteDir и внешний отлавливающий все остальные.

Comment: Вот и пытаюсь решить, пока ничего не получается:)